# SQL Top 1 of two unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen similar questions but nothing that solves my specific problem:

I have two unrelated tables that have a column with a numeric date (e.g. 201704030000). I'm looking to pull the earliest date from either table as one result.

So essentially I need the lowest result from two Top (1) subqueries where both are ordered by date ASC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does what you said you wanted. It takes the top 1 from two union-ed top 1 queries.

```
select top 1 dt
from (
  select top 1 TicketDate as dt
  from t1
  order by dt asc
  union all
  select top 1 TimesheetDate as dt
  from t2
  order by dt asc
  ) u
order by dt asc
```

Comment: Thanks thats almost exactly what I need, I should have mentioned though that the date columns have different names (e.g. TicketDate, TimesheetDate), is there some way to alias them?

Comment: You can simply add the alias to the end of the field name. Example: SELECT TOP 1 TicketDate AS myDate FROM .... UNION SELECT TOP 1 TimesheetDate AS myDate FROM ....

Comment: @simon2015 Added aliasing in the derived table.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would replace top 1 with min() in SqlZim's code. Makes for much shorter and more readable code - but there should be no performance difference.